# Why do I see only one div element being returned?

Tags: python, lxml

Say, I go to this page

https://www.reddit.com/r/starcraft/

Save, its source code. Then use `lxml` in the following way:

```
tree = etree.parse('redditsample.html', parser=etree.HTMLParser());
tree.xpath('//div')
```

And this is what I get:

```
[<Element div at 0x7f185ac9f908>]
```

Why do I get only one element? If one looks into source code, he will see there are way more div elements available. Why aren't they parsed?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if the `redditsample.html` file you saved is the same as https://www.reddit.com/r/starcraft/

reddit enforces rate limiting, so if you’ve run your script multiple times, you may have it that. In that case your saved `redditsample.html` file might only contain a reddit message saying you hit their rate limiting and you need to try your request again later.

Requesting that URL without hitting any rate limiting, the `.xpath('//div')` result is 429 nodes:

```
>>> len(etree.fromstring(requests.get('https://www.reddit.com/r/starcraft/')
    .content, parser=etree.HTMLParser()).xpath('//div'))
429
```